# Sort a file according to a field starting with string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Suppose I have a file so structured

```
/home/zz/AUTHORBOOKS/Author-Chomsky-Who-Rules-the-World.epub
/home/zz/AUTHORBOOKS/Author-Cioran-Il-nulla.epub
/home/zz/BOOKS/Author-Artemis-Mathematica-Examples.nb
/home/zz/Books/Author-Zigniwe-Hisory-Medicine.pdf
/home/z1/OLDBOOKS1/OLDBOOKS2/Author-Watanabe-Waterloo.pdf
/home/z2/OLDBOOKS1/OLDBOOKS2/Author-Barbero-Lepanto.epub.pdf
```

I would like a file sorted this way:

```
/home/zz/BOOKS/Author-Artemis-Mathematica-Examples.nb
/home/z2/OLDBOOKS1/OLDBOOKS2/Author-Barbero-Lepanto.epub.pdf
/home/zz/AUTHORBOOKS/Author-Chomsky-Who-Rules-the-World.epub
/home/zz/AUTHORBOOKS/Author-Cioran-Il-nulla.epub
/home/z1/OLDBOOKS1/OLDBOOKS2/Author-Watanabe-Waterloo.pdf
/home/zz/Books/Author-Zigniwe-History-Medicine.pdf
```

That is, alphabeticallly, according the string `Author-...`

As you can see the position of `Author-...` is not constant.

How can I do this?

Comment: This question would be more interesting if there did not exist a separator (like `-`) to start "key 2". For example, how can we sort using the _whole_ file name?

Comment: Read `man sort` and Knuth's book "Sorting and Searching", vol 4 of Fundamental Algorithms.

Comment: If you think one of the answer is correct, accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to that answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's overkill for the present example because of the [solution proposed in user68186's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1344611/178692), you could more generally do something like this in GNU awk:

```
gawk -F/ '
  function mycmp(i1,v1,i2,v2) {
    m = split(v1,a);
    n = split(v2,b);
    return a[m]"" > b[n]"" ? 1 : a[m]"" < b[n]"" ? -1 : 0
  }
  {
    lines[NR] = $0
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "mycmp";
    for(i in lines) print lines[i]
  }
' file
```

Note that it sorts according to the lexical value of everything after the last `/` - so if the format is `Author-<author name>-<title>.<extension>` that will be

- the fixed string `Author-` (which has no effect, since it has the same weight for all lines); then
- `<author name>-`; then
- `<title>.`; then
- `<extension>`

This is similar to how GNU `sort`'s simple KEYDEF `-t- -k2` works i.e. the effective sort key starts from the `<author name>` and continues to the line end.

An explicit delimiter is omitted from the `split` calls so that they inherit the value of `FS`, making it easy to change for systems that use a different path separator. The appended empty strings `""` in the `mycmp` function force lexical comparison even if the filenames are numerical - see for example [How awk Converts Between Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strings-And-Numbers)

---

If you'd rather stick with the `sort` command, you could leverage GNU awk's [Two-Way Communications with Another Process](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO) to:

- duplicate the last `/`-separated field at the start of the string
- pass the result to a `sort` comnand
- read back the sorted result, remove the duplicated prefix and print

i.e.

```
gawk -F/ '
  BEGIN {OFS=FS; cmd = "sort -d"} 
  {print $NF $0 |& cmd} 
  END {
    close(cmd,"to"); 
    while(cmd |& getline){$1 = ""; print};
    close(cmd,"from")
  }
' file
```

There's a bit of a cheat here in that the absolute paths (lines start with `/`) imply an initial empty field; to handle relative paths you'd need to change `print $NF $0` to `print $NF,$0` to insert the "missing" separator, and then perhaps use a regex `sub()` instead of the simpler `$1 = ""` to remove the leading element.

As well as potentially being faster / more memory efficient than the pure `gawk` solution, this allows other `sort` options to be added straightforwardly ex. `cmd = "sort -d -t " FS " -k1,1r"` .

Comment: Wonderful! I don't quite follow whats going on in the "mycmp" function. Could you point me to a web tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: @user68186 custom sort functions are discussed in the GNU Awk User's Guide at [Controlling Array Traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) BTW please turn your comment into an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I understand it a little better, but there is much to learn in `gawk`. And as you wished I have turned my comment to an answer. :)

Comment: +1 for the added explanation! Now a t bit on `return a[m]"" > b[n]"" ? 1 : a[m]"" < b[n]"" ? -1 : 0` will be great! Thanks again.

Comment: @user68186 it's just two [ternary conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conditional-Exp) in a trenchcoat

Answer (score 3):

#### Try the following `bash` command:

```
sort -t- -d -k2 -o output.txt input.txt
```

It has four options plus the name of the input file `input.txt`. If this file is not in the current directory you will have to provide the `path/to/the/folder/input.txt`. The options and their arguments are as follows:

- -t marks the field separator. We use `-` as the separator, so that everything before and after the `-` are considered separate columns.
- -d indicates dictionary sort. For example Apple is before Berry.
- -k2 indicates the column by which to sort, in this case the second column. Note the first column is everything before the first `-`. For example, `/home/zz/BOOKS/Author`. The second column is in between the first and the second `-`, that is, `Artemis`.
- -o `output.txt` redirects the sorted output to a file rather than to the terminal.

Hope this helps